# Excel, INDIRECT, ADDRESS, MATCH, 2 sheets referral to a picture

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

Can someone help me with a design problem?

In the screenshot, you'll see (1) a list of pipes and (2) a dropdown list or you can fill the name in (CELL G2) and in H2 the picture will pop up (which is found from the list of pipes (1)).

On the picture of CELL H2 there is a formula (=Product) used through Name Manager

```
FX = =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2-1+MATCH(Blad1!$G$2;Blad1!$A$2:$A$5;0);2))
```

'Blad1' means 'Sheet1'.

This works all well. but it stopped working when I try to divide the current sheet into 2.

[image: Outlook of the sheet]

I would like to divided it, each on 1 sheet. So Sheet1: (2) drop down list (the CELLS G2 and H2)
and sheet2: (1) the list of pipes (CELLS A2 to B5).

But then even if I changed the formula to the right sheet name:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2-1+MATCH(Blad1!$G$2;Blad2!$A$2:$A$5;0);2))
```

it won't work?

Can someone help me with this why it isn't working? It does work with hard values, but I want to return it with a picture.

This will help me so much. Thank you.

[[image: Used formula]

[image: Divide into 2 sheets]

Comment: Just an FYI DIRECT and ADDRESS are both volatile, the first formula can be rewritten using INDEX instead: `=INDEX(Blad1!$B$2:$B$5;MATCH(Blad1!$G$2;Blad1!$A$2:$A$5;0))`  And avoid the volatility.

Comment: you need to change the `Blad1!$G$2` to reference the sheet on which you will have that column and that correct cell.  While the `Blad1!$B$2:$B$5` and `Blad1!$A$2:$A$5` should be the other sheet name.